# MYSQLi Select query using form input values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a search page that will allow a user to type values into a "Name" and "Location" field of a form, which will then be used in a MYSQLi query.

But the values are not being parsed into the query.

The `$_POST` is getting the values correctly from the form, and the query will work if a say `WHERE Name = 'name1'`, so the problem seems to be the bind_param is not parsing the value correctly.

Why isn't it working?

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = ?")) {
        $result->bind_param("s", $name);
        $result->execute;
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                      
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Name    </td>";
                echo "<th>Location</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Name . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Location . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            }  
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: [Review the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) carefully. A MySQLi statement object doesn't work with `fetch_object(), fetch_assoc()` like `mysqli::query()` does.  You must first do `bind_resut()` to bind each result column into a variable reference and then call `$result->fetch()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: Why do I need to bind each value to a column? Data is being retrieved with the above code. The fetch command above is working, its the bind_param with the query that isn't working. That's what I am really confused with. Thanks.

Comment: OK I think I fixed it. I am concatenating the form values directly into the query, using a bind_result for the outputted columns. Still don't know if this is the "correct" way to do it but it seems to be working.